# SSRS Displaying Variable Data in a Page Header Not Displaying on Subsequent pages

Tags: reporting-services, header

I have inserted a page header and added a textbox with the expression =ReportItems!co_MainContact.value.  This is the address that I want repeated in each page.  For some reason, the address is printed on the first page, but not in the next few pages.  Is there a reason why this data doesn't show up? I have a logo and a title in the header page and they're showing up in subsequent pages.

The co_MainContact expression is:
=Fields!co_Address1.Value & vbcrlf + Fields!co_City.Value & ", " & Lookup(Fields!co_ProvinceId.Value,Fields!pc_id.Value, Fields!pc_ProvCode.Value, "Province") & ", "& Fields!co_PostalCode.Value & vbcrlf & "Voice: "&Fields!co_MainContact.Value + " Fax: "& Fields!co_FaxNumber.Value  & vbcrlf & "Toll Free: "&Fields!co_PhoneNumber.Value

Report Header properties are default settings and I'm using MS report builder 15.0.19440.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your full report design it's hard to say, if this does not help, please post a screen shot of your full report design, include all grouping as this is usually an important factor.

I would guess you are referencing a textbox that only appears on the first page. References to `ReportItems` don't work in the same way as referencing `Fields`.

So I would think you have a few options...

**Option 1: Change the header expression**

Change the expression in the header to be similar to the expression of the `co_MainContact` textbox but specify the scope as the dataset.

something like

```
=FIRST(Fields!co_Address1.Value, "myDataSetName") & vbcrlf + FIRST(Fields!co_City.Value , "myDataSetName") & .... etc... etc
```

NOTE: the dataset name is case sensitive and must be enclose in quotes.

**Option 2: Add a calculated field to your dataset**

For a cleaner report you could add a new field to your dataset, either in the dataset query, appending all the relevant columns, or you could add in to the dataset fields as a calculated field (from the dataset properties window).

Either way you will end up with a new column and you can reference that column directly in both the `co_MainContact` textbox (simply `=Fields!myNewAddressColumn.Value`) and also in your header. For the header you would use something like `=FIRST(Fields!myNewAddressColumn.Value, "myDataSetName")`

Hopefully one of these options will do the trick, if not post as much as you can, especially the report design.

Comment: Thanks! Option 1 did the trick, however there is one field called ProvinceID where I need to look up in another dataset to retrieve the ProvCode.  The ProvCode and ProvinceID are in different databases and they're not linked so I can't use a query to do the join. Is there a way around it?

Comment: You can use the same process, just change the dataset for each field as appropriate. e.g. `=FIRST(Fields!co_Address1.Value, "myDataSetName") & vbcrlf + FIRST(Fields!pc_ProvCode.Value , "Province")`

Please don't forget to mark answers as accepted (the check box below the vote up/down buttons) when you've ask a question.